# Errror on downloading updates on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Unable to download updates:
failed to refresh cache: E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fixnix/netspeed/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a broken ppa repository in your list of packages.
Run `sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:fixnix/netspeed` and `sudo apt-get update` if you want to remove it.